# Impersonation in asp.net not shared with com object

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, api, com

So I have an ASP DOT NET web service which needs to impersonate Windows Authenticated users. This web service calls into a Com Api to perform database operations.

It seems like the Impersonation does not persist into the Com Api. Is this because the Com DLL is loaded into its own memory space and treated as a separate process? Also what would be some ways to deal with this issue and persist the Impersonation into the Com Api Dll?

Moving the functionality of the Com Api into the dot net code is not an option at this point. Also the Com Api was written in C++.

Comment: What is the server architecture between these components. If they are spread across different servers it could be that you are suffering from the 'double hop' effect. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

Comment: Both the IIS server and Com Api are on the same server.

Comment: That article states impersonation is a Operating System level command, which says to me that this should be working no problem.

Also The Com Api communicates with Sql Server which is also running on the same machine in this testing case.

Comment: I also do not understand fully on what level the impersonation takes place. I notice each Process is owned by a user. Is it this process which becomes impersonated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem. The Com Object is loaded into its own thread and Impersonation being set the way I did is Thread level. Since I have control of the Com Object adding the Windows function CoImpersonateClient(); before any code that needed to be impersonated did the trick.

Here is the article I finally found that resolved the problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q325791